# How do I allow remote connections to my Apache server on my Mac OS X Yosemite?

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache

I have followed the instructions from this guide: http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2014/11/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-yosemite/

And, thankfully, I can access local PHP files via localhost/

However, I want to allow remote connections such that if the user enters my IP address followed by the correct port (which I believe is 80) followed by the file name, they too can access these local PHP files.

What is the next step to make this happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache: how can I access my webpage from a computer outside my network?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454503/apache-how-can-i-access-my-webpage-from-a-computer-outside-my-network)

Comment: Assuming your behind a router, you will need to forward inbound port 80 requests to the internal (192.168.x.x) IP of the Mac hosting Apache. Also be aware if you are doing this from home, many ISPs block inbound port 80 on residential accounts, forcing you to upgrade to a business account.