# Linux server subdomains for multiple sites

Tags: php, linux, apache, subdomain, web-access

I have 2 websites i want to host on a Linux machine using Apache server. Since at this point i am unable to acquire a domain name, i access the server through IP, since I'm not required to have one yet.
The first site is comprised of a few HTML pages and is located in `/var/hostroot/lifeonearth/{all files here}` and the other is comprised of several PHP pages located in `/var/hostroot/webDarts/{all files here}`.
By default when i go to my IP address, it takes me to the default "Your Apache server is working" page. So from here on, how do i make it so that i can access each site through some sort of subdomain like `lifeonearth.(my IP)` or `webDarts.(my IP)` or, am I supposed to access them throug different ports. If it's the latter, how do I go about it?

Comment: Before giving you the answer let me clarify my doubts. You are going to host 2 websites in a single Linux machine right ? Both should be accessible at a time . Is that correct ?

Comment: Is that live server ?

Comment: I don't think so, come to think of it, it's not really necessary for both sites to work simultaneously, i just want to be able to access either of them separately via IP address

Comment: Please have a look at my answer and let me know is that what you required

Answer (score 0):

We have 2 website names.

```
1. example1.test.local  (/var/www/example1) 
2. example2.test.local (/var/www/example2)
```

Now Lets create two files called `example1` and `example2` in  `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

`example1` file looks like as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/example1
ServerName example1.test.local
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/example1>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

as the same way create another file called `example2` and modify the following lines

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/example2
ServerName example2.test.local
```

and

```
<Directory /var/www/example2>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

rest of the file will same as `example1.`

Then enable those two sites

```
a2ensite example1
a2ensite example2
```

Then do apache service restart.

Now we have to do DNS pointing

If your Linux machine is LOCAL then go to your Windows machine where you want to access these websites and open the following file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

and mention your ip and  website name

```
192.168.249.101 example1.test.local
192.168.249.101 example2.test.local
```

Thats it! If you found any difficulties please let me know.

I have replicated this scenario at my end and it works for me. Hope it will work for you!

Comment: think it works. How do i access them outside a local network, or did I misread something

Comment: If it is live server then you have to do DNS pointing for that Ip

Comment: Meaning, if i don't have a domain name, it won't work?

Comment: Please have a look at on this link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454503/apache-how-can-i-access-my-webpage-from-a-computer-outside-my-network